# Is there some Windows application that start recording when detects movement with webcam?

Tags: windows-7, windows, webcam

I want to use my webcam to monitor my room's window to see if someone is invading my home when I'm not at home.

As usual, I leave my notebook turned on all the time downloading torrents and sometimes I access it with my smartphone with [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) to see how the downloads are going. I wish just to use the webcam to record any movement that comes from my window (my webcam will stay pointed at the room window) so that I could see as an "alert" from the application popped on the screen. If I detect any suspicious movement then I can call the security company or the cops.

Does someone know an application for Windows 7 that starts recording from webcam when it detects any movement?

Comment: Sounds dubious ;)

Comment: Feel free to edit and improve the question description :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My former employers, [DeskShare](http://www.deskshare.com), have two products that do just this, WebCam Monitor and Security Monitor Pro. I did a lot of testing on them and they work great. I know there are competitors available that also work but have no experience with them.

Disclaimer: I worked for DeskShare for several years but have no current relationship with the company. However, if you don't like the programs' help files you can blame me.

Comment: +1 for "However, if you don't like the programs' help files you can blame me". ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [Yawcam](http://www.yawcam.com/), it won't record a video but will take a series of pictures when it detects motion (I have every 100ms or something like that for a few seconds.)

(If there is one that would record video that would be great!)